# MSQL How can I use a many statement in NOT IN

Tags: mysql, notin

I try to execute this query:

```
SELECT ISBN FROM table2 WHERE 
NOT IN ISBN=('8426429807','840149768X')
group by ISBN 
ORDER BY AVG(`Book-Rating`) DESC LIMIT 10
```

but I get error this shape

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IN ISBN=('8426429807','840149768X')

How can I use many isbn in Not In

Comment: where X not in Y!

Comment: Not the cause of your problem but you should avoid using dashes in column names.

Comment: Including a minus ('-') character in a table/column identifier is just about the dumbest idea it's possible to have in sql. You have been warned.

Comment: Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

[`Not In()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in) syntax is:

```
expr NOT IN (value,...)
```

Basically, column/expression should come before `Not In` and you do not use `=` operator. It should be:

```
SELECT ISBN
FROM table2
WHERE ISBN NOT IN ('8426429807',
                   '840149768X')
GROUP BY ISBN
ORDER BY AVG(`Book-Rating`) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

---

Another way of writing same query is using `NOT (expr IN (value, ...))`:

```
SELECT ISBN
FROM table2
WHERE NOT (ISBN IN ('8426429807',
                    '840149768X'))
GROUP BY ISBN
ORDER BY AVG(`Book-Rating`) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: book-rating? Next you'll be dividing a book a by its rating !

Comment: @Strawberry fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `where column_name NOT IN ( col_value1, col_value2)`

```
select ISBN from table2
where ISBN NOT IN ('8426429807','840149768X')
group by ISBN 
ORDER BY AVG(`Book-Rating`) DESC LIMIT 10
```